# In ajax success message through php comes in unwanted text

Tags: php, ajax

I want an alert message if Item is successfully inserted into cart. But the result show unwanted charterers why? like this [image]

In last shows my desire message. 
Here is the code:
 Ajax:

```
function myFunctionguest(val) {
  var itemid = val;
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {temp: itemid},
        url: "listhelpguest.php",
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(data)
        {
            window.alert(data);
        } 
    });  
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  include 'dbconfig.php';
  echo $guestuserid = $_COOKIE["guestuser"];
  $itmid = $_POST['temp'];
  $sq ="SELECT * from item where item_id ='$itmid'";
  $re =mysqli_query($conn, $sq);
  $ro =mysqli_fetch_assoc($re);
  $name = $ro["name"];         
  $sp = $ro["selling_price"];         
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE item_id = '$itmid' and gid ='$guestuserid'";
  $res1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  $rows = mysqli_num_rows($res1); 
  if ($rows >=1) {
        echo "Item Already in Your Cart";
    }
  else {  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cart (email,gid, item_id, qty, itotprice) VALUES ('$guestuserid','$guestuserid', '$itmid', '1', '$sp')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
         echo $name . " Successfully Added to Cart";
    } 
    else {
          echo "Try Again";
    } 
  }
?>
```

Comment: Open your Devtools and go to Network tab, see what response the server is sending you when you make this request. Probably something weird about the `$name` variable, or maybe the encoding isn't right

Comment: Nevermind. You're echoing the user's cookie `echo $guestuserid = $_COOKIE["guestuser"];`. That's why you're having this extra stuff.

Comment: Try debugging each line till you find the issue. You've got a better chance of fixing it

Comment: sorry thaks its works now

Answer (score 1):

Those unwanted characters are showing up there because you're echoing a key from the `$_COOKIE` array, in the following line:

```
echo $guestuserid = $_COOKIE["guestuser"];
```

Remove the `echo` and you should be good to go.